# iphone device current orientation in ViewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios

Please, help me. I have methods:

```
-(void) getCurrentOrientation{

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        NSLog(@"portrait");
    } else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeRight");
    } else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeLeft");
    }   
}
```

but when i call this getCurrentOrientation throw viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self getCurrentOrientation];

}
```

NSLog is empty. Whats wrong ?
I also try

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    if ( ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)) {
        NSLog(@"portrait");

    } else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) 

    {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeRight"); 
    }

}
```

but that varint also empty.

**I need to know in which ORIENTATION user launch APP!**

Please, give me any advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct and there is no problem.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

This statement only works in original devices.

However you want to check in simulator you can check as

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    // portrait             
} else {
    // landscape
}
```

**Update:**

I have tested for you in both device and simulator. Initially it would show portrait only in viewDidLoad though you will keep device in landscape. First Controller will look into shouldAutoRotate method.

**You should not depend** on `viewDidLoad` for initial orientation. You should depend on shouldAutorotate method initially for exact orientation.

Comment: Thank you. But when i run on simulator in LANDSCAPE mode, NSlog output PORTRAIT. So I am not sure that it will correct work on real device

Comment: I select in Project - Target - Summary - Supported Device Orientation only LANDSCAPE. But when I run app in sumulator with your function Nslog output portrait. And why I should not depend ? I just need to know in which orientation USER run app.

Comment: As I told you Though user run application keeping landscape mode initially it will load portrait mode if you are supporting both portrait/landscape mode. And after execution of shouldAutorotate function it will come to know that currently it is landscape mode and you should put your code in that only. Hope this clears the concept. Leave comment if still have doubt.

Comment: Thank you ! Ithink thats solution ! Thank you again !

Answer (score 8):

When the app first loads, UIDevice.current.orientation isn't valid.  But UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation is.  UIDevice.current.orientation is the better way to check orientation, in general, though.  So, this method will handle all situations

```
var isLandscape: Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.orientation.isValidInterfaceOrientation 
        ? UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape 
        : UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape
}
```

Comment: This right here, I can't believe that this wasn't marked as the correct answer, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Try replace your shouldAutorotateMethod by below shouldAutorotate

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
  {
       if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
          NSLog(@"portrait");    
       } else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {       
          NSLog(@"LandscapeRight");        
       } else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {      
          NSLog(@"LandscapeLeft"); 
       }   
       return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
  }
```

This may help you out.

Comment: just tell me, please, why ? I don have any problem with shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. I have problem with viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just check the orientation of app then use following code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BOOL isPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);
    // now do whatever you need
}
```

or

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    if  (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        //landscape view code
    } 
    else
    {
         //portrait view code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in swift 3 or swift 4 . you can use this code in viewDidLoad()..

```
let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
 if orientation == .portrait {
        // portrait   
 } else if orientation == .landscapeRight || orientation == 
.landscapeLeft{
         // landscape     
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your `viewDidLoad` called? Have you put a breakpoint in there?

What about just printing `NSLog(@"%i", [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])`?

The documentation says, that the orientation always returns 0, if you didn't call `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`. Maybe calling it just before you try to get the orientation is not enough. Try to move the call to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

However, the best thing is using the orientation supplied by the controller -  `[UIViewController interfaceOrientation]` and the parameter passed to  `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes orientation always returns 0 and i put (as I write above) beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications. But orientation also returns 0.

Comment: That's why I am saying that you should try to move it to `[UIApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]`